# How to use Redis in a web application using lettuce API in Java?

Tags: java, redis, lettuce

I want to use Redis in a web application. To do this I have used Lettuce API an created a static `StatefulRedisConnection` in my listener and used it in my other classes. to execute Redis commands, I made a `RedisCommands` instance in the same way of creating connections. I have read the documentation of lettuce and found out that this way I used is correct. But as I want to terminate my program, tomcat warn me for a memory leak but I cannot find the problem.

My code:

```
public class ContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
public static RedisClient redisClient;
public static StatefulRedisConnection<String, String> connection;
public static RedisCommands<String, String> redis;

public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    redisClient = new RedisClient(RedisURI.create("redis://localhost:6379"));
    connection = redisClient.connect();
    redis = connection.sync();
}

public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    redis.close();
    connection.close();
    redisClient.shutdown();
}
```

Any help is appreciated...

Thanks.

stack trace:

```
    /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.26/bin/catalina.sh stop
03-Dec-2015 12:49:40.992 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
03-Dec-2015 12:49:40.993 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
03-Dec-2015 12:49:41.049 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
03-Dec-2015 12:49:41.102 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service Catalina
03-Dec-2015 12:49:41.112 WARNING [localhost-startStop-2] com.lambdaworks.redis.RedisChannelHandler.close Connection is already closed
03-Dec-2015 12:49:43.342 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@2e242d5c]) and a value of type [io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap] (value [io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap@3dbe5969]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
03-Dec-2015 12:49:43.342 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@2e242d5c]) and a value of type [io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap] (value [io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap@3f755d05]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
03-Dec-2015 12:49:43.342 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@2e242d5c]) and a value of type [io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap] (value [io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap@30b4d97a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
03-Dec-2015 12:49:43.342 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@2e242d5c]) and a value of type [io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap] (value [io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap@7f0eab14]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
03-Dec-2015 12:49:43.343 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@2e242d5c]) and a value of type [io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap] (value [io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap@7f56b45e]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
03-Dec-2015 12:49:43.343 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@2e242d5c]) and a value of type [io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap] (value [io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap@6a5e43c4]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
03-Dec-2015 12:49:43.343 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@2e242d5c]) and a value of type [io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap] (value [io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap@7c3738fc]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
03-Dec-2015 12:49:43.343 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@2e242d5c]) and a value of type [io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap] (value [io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap@766b6a65]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
03-Dec-2015 12:49:43.343 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@2e242d5c]) and a value of type [io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap] (value [io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap@3cd5d4b2]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
03-Dec-2015 12:49:43.343 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@2e242d5c]) and a value of type [io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap] (value [io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap@240df08f]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
03-Dec-2015 12:49:43.344 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [ROOT] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@2e242d5c]) and a value of type [io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap] (value [io.netty.util.internal.InternalThreadLocalMap@6138cc2a]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
03-Dec-2015 12:49:43.352 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
03-Dec-2015 12:49:43.454 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
03-Dec-2015 12:49:43.470 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
03-Dec-2015 12:49:43.470 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

Comment: Can you post the details on the memory leak message in Tomcat? The code above looks good, `redis.close()` does the same as `connection.close()`, so no need to call both methods.

Comment: @mp911de Tomcat made an error as severe and told that the Netty threads do not terminate. I searched that and I saw an issue about this problem in https://github.com/wg/lettuce/issues/34 which told that Netty threads are not daemon threads, so they hold the process open.

Comment: Please note, wg/lettuce is no longer maintained. The Github repo is mp911de/lettuce. Can you post also the stack trace right after the `redisClient.shutdown()` call?

Comment: @mp911de I have added the stack trace.